# function arguments is immutable

Tags: javascript

for each function, there is an `arguments` attribute.
When I want to set it, it does not take the value.
I am curious, how the `arguments` attribute implemented internally to allow this behavior, where I cannot modify it? What I want to achieve is to implement an attribute that could not be modified in my object, can someone shine me some light on how to achieve that.

```
  var a=function b(){

      };
      a.arguments="hello";
      console.log(a.arguments); //still null
```

Comment: I think you need to have a parameters in your function first... `function b(paramaters){}`

Comment: Though the `arguments` object is a special built-into the language object, even in plain Javascript, you can have a property with a getter, but no setter or a property that is configured to not be writable via `Object.defineProperty()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) and [Object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

The example from mozilla.org

```
obj1 = {
  internal: {}
};

Object.freeze(obj1);
obj1.internal.a = 'aValue';

obj1.internal.a // 'aValue'

// To make obj fully immutable, freeze each object in obj.
// To do so, we use this function.
function deepFreeze(obj) {

  // Retrieve the property names defined on obj
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

  // Freeze properties before freezing self
  propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var prop = obj[name];

    // Freeze prop if it is an object
    if (typeof prop == 'object' && !Object.isFrozen(prop))
      deepFreeze(prop);
  });

  // Freeze self
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}

obj2 = {
  internal: {}
};

deepFreeze(obj2);
obj2.internal.a = 'anotherValue';
obj2.internal.a; // undefined
```

`arguments` can be modified inside the function like any other variable so it is not as protected as you may think. Setting variables inside functions will not be accessible outside of the function like arguments is. I see what you are trying to go for so [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) and [Object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) might be of interest to you instead.

*

### This question is not specifically about `arguments` in a functions scope. If you have reached this page in regards to this, see below

*

The arguments parameter is reserved to provide you the arguments passed to the function itself.

Consider the following code ::

**Set function to log arguments to the console:**

```
function test() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

**Call test with an argument:**

```
test('test');
```

**Returns:**

```
test
```

`arguments` is now a part of the test functions prototype and can not be altered except through setting them by calling the function with arguments.

To be more clear. You can not add default values for arguments in Javascript. As I imagine this may be what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew it is reserved, the keypoint is that how can we implement such behavior  for our object, where an attribute cannot be changed?

Comment: @william007 What exactly are you trying to do? You want to know why `arguments` is immutable or you want to have similar functionality for your own properties? Please explain clearly in the question.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks for the comments, modified that question.

Comment: @william007, I updated my answer. Thank you for clarifying your question